# How to prove something is a sufficient statistic?

Tags: statistics

If you have $n$ random variables that are iid with density $\frac{1}{p}e^{-x/p}$, how do you show that the sum of the $x_i$'s is a sufficient statistic?

Attempt: Take likelihood function and express in terms of $g(p)h(x)$ and use factorization theorem to show that it is a sufficient statistic.
So likelihood = $\frac{1}{p^n} \exp(\sum \frac{-x_i}{p}) = \frac{1}{p^n} \exp(\frac{1}{p}  \sum (-x_i))$.

Comment: If I messed up your calculation while trying to format it, let me know.

Comment: lord12, You have not accepted any answers to your previous questions. It is generally considered rude in this site to keep posting questions, without accepting answers to previous ones. Please pick the answers that helped you the most and accept them.

Comment: lord12, there's a check mark by each answer.  Click on the one by the answer that you found most helpful.  (And it would also be considered polite to upvote - click on the little up arrow next to the answer - each answer that you found helpful.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are exponential random variables. Consider the joint probability density. This would be 
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{p}e^{-\frac{x_i}{p}}=p^{-n}e^{-\frac{1}{p}T(x)},\qquad T(x)= \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$$

Let $h(x) =1$ and $g(p,t) = p^{-n}e^{-t/p}$. Then the result follows from the [factorization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Fisher.E2.80.93Neyman_factorization_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Let $y$ represent observations and let $x$ be the latent variable of interest, then we have the following equivalent statements that can be helpful in proving that $t=t(y)$ is sufficient statistic wrt to our model $p_y(y;x)$

Non-Bayesian Viewpoint

1. Definition: $p_{y|t}(y|t; x)$ is not a function of x
2. Proportional likelihoods (same ML estimate): $L_y(x) \propto L_t(x)$
3. Neyman factorization theorem: $p_y(y;x) = a(t(y),x)\times b(y)$

Bayesian Viewpoint

1. Conditioning on $t$ removes dependence on $x$: $p_{y|t,x}(y|t(y),x)
       = p_{y|t}(y|t(y))$
2. Same posteriors: $p_{x|y}(x|y) = p_{x|t}(x|t(y))$
3. Data processing inequality $I(X;Y) \geq I(X;Z)$ for a Markov Chain
   $X\rightarrow Y\rightarrow Z$ is satisfied with equality: $I(X;Y) =
   I(X;T(Y))$ if $Z = T(Y)$, i.e. sufficient statistic of data $Y$.

For example for an exponential family

$p_y(y;x) = \exp \{\lambda(x) t(y) + \beta(y) - \alpha(x)\}$

where $\lambda(x)$ are natural parameters, $t(y)$ is sufficient statistic, $\beta(y)$ is log-base function and $\alpha(x)$ is log-normalizer, we can show that $t(y)$ is sufficient statistic by applying Neyman factorization theorem:

$p_y(y;x) = \exp \{\lambda(x) t(y) - \alpha(x)\} \times \exp\{\beta(y)\} = a(t(y), x) \times b(y)$